# How to submit a field collection from a form into a created node

Tags: nodes

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me with this :)

I have a field collection called field_formations. Inside it I have 2 fields:

- field_technologies - (reference to a taxonomy).
- field_diploma -(how it's also a field collection which contain 2 other   fields:
- field_name(reference to a taxonomy)
- field_establishement (text plain)
                 ).

  I've created a form with 3 field forms
- technology
- diplome_name
- establishement

  and into the submit form i would like to submit values of this forms into  the node created at first.

  I tried to setValues like this :

$node->field_formations->field_technologies->setValue($values['technology']);

but it dosen't work 
Can any body have a suggetion??

 
PS : I'm using drupal 8

Answer (score 0):

You need the id of the field collection item (grand one) which you can find inside the node object. Then you load the field collection by that id as an entity. Edit this field collection and save it as an entity. The point is that you have to load the field collectin entity, make changes and save it.

Comment: Can you explain me more with an exemple?

Comment: I think the same should apply more or less for Drupal 8. First you have a node >> a field_collection meta field that holds the id of the field_collection associated with that node >> once you have loaded this integer, load the field collection entity using entity_load(). From this point work with it as you would do for any other entity using the entity_api like logic under Drupal 7. See this: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21entity.inc/function/entity_load/8

Comment: thnks .... but how about loading the value of the forms in fields related to field collection?